# sending and recieving through serial

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino-uno

I have got a simple program running in the uno that measures the distance using ping sensor and now i am trying to control some servos based on the distance in python but the conditional thingy is not working even in a simple code like this

```
import serial
data = serial.Serial('COM7',9600)
while(1):        
    if(data.inWaiting()>0):
        dist = data.readline()
        if(dist>100):
            print("dist is greater than 100")
        else:
            print("this shit does not work")
```

It is always the if that works, I am a noob please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data from serial port type is `str`

You are trying to read the data and use `if .... > 100` this will never work.

You need to read the data to a buffer and then check it, Also you need some sync frame to know you have got all the data(it's not a must but its much eaiser)

for example let say the read data is `100!` and `!` is your sync frame.

```
import serial
my_serial = serial.Serial('COM7',9600)
my_data = ""
while(1):        
    if(my_serial.inWaiting()>0):
        my_data = my_serial.readline()
        if '!' in my_data:
            break

my_data = [:my_data.find("!")]
if int(my_data) > 100:
    print("dist is greater than 100")
else:
    print("this shit does not work")
```

Comment: You need to adjust it to your hardware, try to read the data using a `for` loop and print the result.